# Why is YubiHSM an HSM?

Tags: yubikey, hsm

What makes the YubiHSM an HSM?

Most HSMs I have seen have more memory and are faster, perhaps due to crypto-accelerators. They're generally big and inserted in data center racks, or plugged as PCIe cards.

But the YubiHSM is tiny, I was wondering what makes it an HSM?

Comment: From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module): "These modules traditionally come in the form of a plug-in card or ..." and at the bottom, YubiKeyHSM is listed as an HSM vendor.

Answer (score 9):

Size and performance don't matter, as a *hardware security module* (HSM) is defined by its functions to perform cryptographic operations and protection. From Peter Smirnoff on Cryptomathic: [Understanding Hardware Security Modules (HSMs)](https://www.cryptomathic.com/news-events/blog/understanding-hardware-security-modules-hsms):

> The hardware security module (HSM) is a special “trusted” network
> computer performing a variety of cryptographic operations: key
> management, key exchange, encryption etc.
>
> It seems to be obvious that cryptographic operations must be performed
> in a trusted environment. When I say trusted, I mean “no viruses, no
> malware, no exploit, no unauthorized access.” An HSM is trusted
> because it:
>
> 1. Is built on top of specialized hardware. The hardware is well-tested
>    and certified in special laboratories.
> 2. Has a security-focused OS.
> 3. Has limited access via a network interface that is strictly controlled
>    by internal rules.
> 4. Actively hides and protects cryptographic material.

You can find the same list of the key properties of a HSM e.g. from Doron Gez: [What Is a Hardware Security Module](https://hubsecurity.io/what-is-a-hardware-security-module-hsm/). Although YubiHSM is *nano form factor*, it meets these requirements ([YubiHSM 2 Product Overview](https://developers.yubico.com/YubiHSM2/Product_Overview/)). While bigger appliances could do these operations faster and store more keys, that only affects their possible use cases.